# Lenovo Ideapad 100 screen replacement

Tags: laptop

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100 laptop. After using it more, than 10-15 mins, the monitor starts blinking. When I connect my laptop to a TV, the TV is not blinking, but the laptop screen continue blinking.
What can be the problem? May the screen replacement slow the problem?

Comment: This Lenovo has a special section of it's own at Lenovo Forums "IDEAPAD" https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/tag/ideapad/tg-p/category-id/Community-EN you may have better luck there.

Comment: Levono Parts Lookup, https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/partslookup  Make sure you have the right screen type (see this page) https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-U-and-S-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-ideapad-S540-find-out-display-type-before-purchase/m-p/4537583

Answer (score 1):

Screen Twitching ?
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx/330S-15IKB-GTX1050-Display-is-twitching/m-p/4549906

> 10-17-2019 02:53 AM
>
> Suggest you uninstall VGA driver,
>
> 1) (win+ x m), uninstall the Display adapter driver in device manager
>
> 2) Updated the latest VGA driver in lenovo vantage online